# Create Page With wp_insert_post() and AJAX

Tags: ajax, wp-insert-post

I've been trying to figure out how to create a post (or any custom post type) with `wp_insert_post()` and  AJAX...so far to no avail.

What I hope to achieve:

- Any user (not just logged in ones, I don't want to mess with permissions for now) can create a post
- To create the post I only want one input and one button and only the title can be created (other stuff is set default).

To start this I made a very simple plugin, here's the PHP; which...

1. enqueues my JS
2. attempts (and apparently fails) to create a function for inserting a post with `wp_insert_post()`
3. has a super simple shortcode for displaying the field to use to create the post/initiate the AJAX.

---

```
/* Enqueue JS
----- */ 

function post_via_ajax_scripts() {  
    wp_register_script( 'post-via-ajax-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'post_via_ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'post-via-ajax-js', 'pva_params', array( 'pva_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'post-via-ajax-js' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'post_via_ajax_scripts');

//Add Ajax Actions
add_action('wp_post_via_ajax', 'post_via_ajax');
add_action('wp_post_via_ajax', 'post_via_ajax');

/* WP Insert Post Function
----- */ 

function post_via_ajax()
{

    $query_post_via_ajax = $_POST;
    $post_title = ($query_post_via_ajax['post_title']) ? $query_post_via_ajax['post_title'] : false;

    // Create post object
    $new_pva_post = array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($post_title ),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $new_pva_post );
    exit();
};    
/* Form Shortcode
----- */ 

function post_via_ajax_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<input id="post_title" name="post_title" type="text"><button id="create_post">Create Post</button>';
}

add_shortcode( 'post_via_ajax', 'post_via_ajax_shortcode' );
```

And here is my JS, which...

1. has a very simple validation requiring the title to be more than 5 charachters
2. attempts (and fails) to create the post via ajax and pass the `'post_title'` to the `post_via_ajax()` function

---

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {

    $('#create_post').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#post_title').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 3) {
            $('#create_post').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#create_post').click(function(event){
                post_via_ajax();
            });
        } else {
            $('#create_post').attr('disabled',true);    
        }
    });

    // Return Post Title Field Value
    function returnNewPostTitle(){
        var newPostTitleValue = $('#post_title').val();
        return newPostTitleValue;
    }

    // AJAX > Get City Posts
    function post_via_ajax()
    {
        console.log('woo');
        var pva_ajax_url = pva_params.pva_ajax_url;

        //alert('woo');*/
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: pva_ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'post_via_ajax',
                post_title: returnNewPostTitle(),
            },
            beforeSend: function ()
            {
                console.log('sending');
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log('yay');
            },
            error: function()
            {
                console.log('nay');

            }
        })
    }
});
```

At this point I have no idea what I'm doing, so I would really appreciate any insights, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have solution for adding Featured image along with ?
Im facing issues with adding featured image and once the post is created show the url of the post

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after some fiddling, I've got things working.

It turns out that I was setting the `add_action` hooks incorrectly for the AJAX part.

The hooks need to be:

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_MYFUNCTION', 'MYFUNCTION' );`

and

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_MYFUNCTION', 'MYFUNCTION' );`

...in my case and original code the function ('MYFUNCTION') in question was to create a post via `wp_insert_post().`

So, after cleaning up my namin conventions and code a bit, I have the following:

PHP

```
/**
 Plugin Name: Post via Ajax
 */

/* Enqueue JS
----- */ 

function pva_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'pva-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'pva.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'pva-js', 'pva_params', array( 'pva_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pva-js' );
};

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pva_scripts');

// creating Ajax call for WordPress
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pva_create', 'pva_create' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pva_create', 'pva_create' );

/* WP Insert Post Function
----- */ 

function pva_create()
{

    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];

    // Create post object
    $new_pva_post = array(
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'post_title'    => $post_title,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $new_pva_post );
    exit();
};



/* Form Shortcode
----- */ 

function pva_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    ob_start();
    include(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'post_via_ajax_field.php');
    $ret = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    return $ret;
        //pva();
};

add_shortcode( 'pva', 'pva_shortcode' );
```

JS

---

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {

    $('#create_post').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#post_title').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 3) {
            $('#create_post').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#create_post').attr('disabled',true);    
        }
    });

    $('#create_post').click(function(event){
        post_via_ajax();
    });

    // Return Post Title Field Value
    function returnNewPostTitle(){
        var newPostTitleValue = $('#post_title').val();
        return newPostTitleValue;
    }

    // AJAX > Get City Posts
    function post_via_ajax()
    {
        var pva_ajax_url = pva_params.pva_ajax_url;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: pva_ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'pva_create',
                post_title: returnNewPostTitle()
            },
            beforeSend: function ()
            {
                console.log('sending');
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log('yay');
            },
            error: function()
            {
                console.log('nay');

            }
        })
    }
});
```

So, with this as a plugin and using the shortcode [pva], you can create a post from the front-end. Obviously this was only intended to be quite basic so I'd imagine you could adapt/adjust to your needs. Hope this helps someone. :)

EDIT: I also just made a super basic [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dornstudio/WP-Post-Via-AJAX)  with the code.